# Force all users to recieve emails to discussion board posts and reply

Tags: outlook, discussion-board

I want to be able to force users to receive emails from discussion board, whenever a new discussion is added, and the ability to un follow a specific discussion.

I don't want users to subscribe to this discussion board, I want the administrator to be able to add the users he wants.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer would be to create an alert that sends an email to a distribution list containing all of your users.  Exactly how you would do that differs widely depending on your environment.  It could be as simple as creating a distribution list in Exchange to creating a service account in AD that forwards emails to a FIM list.  You will have to talk with your infrastructure folks to find out the details.

When talking to them, be sure to bring up the subject of maintaining that list as there are sometimes things that can be done automatically via Active Directory.

Comment: But how will the distribution list receive emails when a new discussion or reply is added to this discussion board?